# Unable to upload a excel file of size 5MB and getting the following error

Tags: codeigniter

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 223 bytes) in
>   /home/greengalaxy/public_html/ci/system/database/DB_query_builder.php
>   on line 1589

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your memory_limit in the php ini.

In the ini file look for

```
memory_limit = 32M ;
```

and change it to

```
memory_limit = 64M ;
```

If you dont have access to the ini file try adding the following before you execute the function causing the error:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
```

If you carn't do the above try adding it to your .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a problem of Codeigniter**.

You are seeing this error because of PHP memory limitation. You can set this accordingly

> Xampp ini file path:- C:\xampp\php\php.ini

Now You need to make some below changes

```
memory_limit = 64M ; //default is 32M
```

OR

you can use .htaccess file and add below line

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

OR

Not recommended but you can add below line in config file(.php file)

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```